# Add a new element/field to every JSON array/record in an existing JSON file - python 3

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have JSON files that consists of 10+ records, like the one below.
Example:

```
[
  {
    "ID": null,
    "entity": "xxx",
    "Name": "Abc",
  },
  {
    "ID": null,
    "entity": "yyy",
    "Name": "efg",
  }
]
```

I want to add a new element "Date": "xx/xx/xx" to every record, like this:

```
[
  {
    "ID": null,
    "entity": "xxx",
    "Name": "Abc",
    "Date": "xx/xx/xx"
  },
  {
    "ID": null,
    "entity": "yyy",
    "Name": "efg",
    "Date": "xx/xx/xx"
  }
]
```

The order does not matter.

So far I have something like this:

```
date = 'xx-xx-xx'

def file(data, json):
    with pathlib.Path(json).open('r+') as upfile:
        fdata = json.load(upfile)
        fdata.append(data)
        upfile.seek(0)
        json.dump(fdata, updfile)
...
new_ele = {'Date: ': date}
file(new_ele, file.json)
```

But my result is like this:

```
[
  {
    "ID": null,
    "entity": "xxx",
    "Name": "Abc",
  },
  {
    "ID": null,
    "entity": "yyy",
    "Name": "efg",
  },
  { 
    "Date": "xx-xx-xx"
  }
]
```

How can I get the Date into every single record?

Thank you

Comment: `json` and `file` are poor names for variables/functions. You should loop through all elements of your jsons. Then you can set a new `Date` key for each element: `elt['Date']=date`

Comment: The variable/func names are just examples, I don't actually have it like that. When I do var['str']=x, it gives me a TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str.

Comment: That's because `var` is a list and not a dictionary. please share the code you're running otherwise it's impossible to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I posted all I could, the rest of the codes have nothing to do with this. I don't have any lists or dictionaries. Just actual JSON files located in a folder on the system.

Answer (score 0):

Once imported, your json is a list of dictionaries. So go through all list elements (which are dictionaries) and update them with the [update](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_update.asp) method:

```
def update_json(data, json_path):
    with pathlib.Path(json_path).open('r+') as upfile:
        fdata = json.load(upfile)
        for elt in fdata:
            elt.update(data)
        upfile.seek(0)
        json.dump(fdata, upfile)
```